# Using array_merge_recursive with numeric keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I've been searching through SO and come across a couple solutions that all feel like hacks for getting around the default `array_merge_recursive` behavior on numeric keys. For instance, I've read that you can add an underscore to the beginning, changing your number to a string.

Anyway, here's my data set and intended outcome...

```
array ( "Name1", "Name2", "Name3" );
array ( "Data1", "Data2", "Data3" );
array ( "Price1", "Price2", "Price3" );
```

Intended outcome:

```
array ( 1 => array ( "Name1", "Data1", "Price1" ), 2 => array ( "Name2", "Data2", "Price2" ), 3 => array ( "Name3", "Data3", "Price3" );
```

I'm sure you're aware of how array_merge_recursive normally operates with numeric keys... Here's my current merged results.

```
array ( "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Price1", "Price2", "Price3");
```

Is there a proper method for this? What are the pros and cons to individual methods, like adding an underscore to create a string key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple workaround would be a completely different approach, like:

```
$merged = array_map(function () { return func_get_args(); }, $array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Comment: I like that. All the other methods involve creating custom functions and multiple lines of code. This is the sort of solution I was looking for and this works as I hoped for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$merge_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    $row = array();
    $row[] = $array1[$i];
    $row[] = $array2[$i];
    $row[] = $array3[$i];
    $merged_array[] = $row;
}
```

That should work.

Comment: thats kinda booring,though... and its also not recursive.